# Comparing values in AngularJS ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a JSON object which includes a number of clients, and per client I have a number of months and payment made in certain date ranges in that month.

I am trying to loop through this list of customers to show a table per customer and in this table I show the payments made in that month.  The tricky part is that I need to highlight when the payments made varied from the previous period.  My issue is that I managed to compare the payments in the same month, however am not managing to compare the payment made in the first period of the month, with the last period of the previous month.

Here is my JSON (which is being returned by a legacy system):

```
{  
 "customers":[  
    {  
     "name":"John",
     "months":{  
        "1":{  
           "details":[  
              {  
                 "startDate":1483225200000,
                 "endDate":1483830000000,
                 "payment":250
              },
              {  
                 "startDate":1483916400000,
                 "endDate":1485817200000,
                 "payment":350
              }
           ]
        },
        "2":{  
           "details":[  
              {  
                 "startDate":1485903600000,
                 "endDate":1487026800000,
                 "payment":350
              },
              {  
                 "startDate":1487113200000,
                 "endDate":1488236400000,
                 "payment":350
              }
           ]
        },
        "3":{  
           "details":[  
              {  
                 "startDate":1488322800000,
                 "endDate":1490911200000,
                 "payment":250
              }
           ]
        },
        "4":{  
           "details":[  
              {  
                 "startDate":1490997600000,
                 "endDate":1491688800000,
                 "payment":275
              },
              {  
                 "startDate":1491775200000,
                 "endDate":1493503200000,
                 "payment":275
              }
           ]
        }
     }
  },
  {  
     "name":"Bob",
     "months":{  
        "1":{  
           "details":[  
              {  
                 "startDate":1483225200000,
                 "endDate":1483830000000,
                 "payment":250
              },
              {  
                 "startDate":1483916400000,
                 "endDate":1485817200000,
                 "payment":350
              }
           ]
        },
        "2":{  
           "details":[  
              {  
                 "startDate":1485903600000,
                 "endDate":1487026800000,
                 "payment":350
              },
              {  
                 "startDate":1487113200000,
                 "endDate":1488236400000,
                 "payment":350
              }
           ]
        },
        "3":{  
           "details":[  
              {  
                 "startDate":1488322800000,
                 "endDate":1490911200000,
                 "payment":250
              }
           ]
        },
        "4":{  
           "details":[  
              {  
                 "startDate":1490997600000,
                 "endDate":1491688800000,
                 "payment":275
              },
              {  
                 "startDate":1491775200000,
                 "endDate":1493503200000,
                 "payment":275
              }
           ]
        }
     }
  },
  {  
     "name":"Jane",
     "months":{  
        "1":{  
           "details":[  
              {  
                 "startDate":1483225200000,
                 "endDate":1483830000000,
                 "payment":250
              },
              {  
                 "startDate":1483916400000,
                 "endDate":1485817200000,
                 "payment":350
              }
           ]
        },
        "2":{  
           "details":[  
              {  
                 "startDate":1485903600000,
                 "endDate":1487026800000,
                 "payment":350
              },
              {  
                 "startDate":1487113200000,
                 "endDate":1488236400000,
                 "payment":350
              }
           ]
        },
        "3":{  
           "details":[  
              {  
                 "startDate":1488322800000,
                 "endDate":1490911200000,
                 "payment":250
              }
           ]
        },
        "4":{  
           "details":[  
              {  
                 "startDate":1490997600000,
                 "endDate":1491688800000,
                 "payment":275
              },
              {  
                 "startDate":1491775200000,
                 "endDate":1493503200000,
                 "payment":275
              }
           ]
        }
     }
  }
 ]
}
```

And here is my HTML where im trying to loop using ng-repeat and trying to apply the class "highlight" when the payment made is different from the previous one:

```
<table ng-repeat="customer in customersList">
<tbody ng-repeat="month in customer.months">
    <tr ng-repeat="detail in customer.details track by $index">
        <td data-ng-class="{'highlight' : month.details[$index-1].payment != month.details[$index].payment && $index > 0}">{{::detail.payment}} {{month.details[$index-1].payment != month.details[$index].payment && $index > 0}}</td>
        <td data-ng-class="{'highlight' : month.details[$index-1].payment != month.details[$index].payment && $index > 0}">{{::detail.payment | currency}} {{$parent.customers.months[$index].details[$index-1].payment}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I tried to use $parent to try to access the previous month and be able to compare the last payment of the previous month with the first payment of the new month however failed miserably.  Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong and if this is possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

Your current implementation is failing because `$index` is the index in `month.details` and you want the index in `customer.months`.

This is the kind of thing that [the `ng-init` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) is intended for.

I'm not 100% sure how you are intending to compare the payments, but I believe you want something like this:

```
<table ng-repeat="customer in customersList">
<tbody ng-repeat="month in customer.months">
    <tr ng-init="monthIndex = $index" ng-repeat="detail in customer.details track by $index">
        <td data-ng-class="{'highlight' : customer.months[monthIndex - 1].details[$index].payment != month.details[$index].payment && monthIndex > 0}">
            {{::detail.payment}} {{customers.months[monthIndex - 1].details[$index] != month.details[$index].payment && $index > 0}}
        </td>
        <td data-ng-class="{'highlight' : customer.months[monthIndex - 1].details[$index-1].payment != month.details[$index].payment && monthIndex > 0}">
            {{::detail.payment | currency}} {{customers.months[monthIndex - 1].details[$index].payment}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

This sets `monthIndex` to the index of the current month prior to entering the `month.details` loop. This scope variable is available within the `month.details` loop so you can use `monthIndex - 1` to look at the previous month.

Comment: I arrived somewhat closer with your reply :)   - The only issue i have is that i need to set the monthIndex to be equal to the appropriate number - like 1 would be January, 2 February etc.  I can get an instance where I only get months from June till December (the above example only shows Jan till April for instance) and therefore the index is not matching. Is there a way to set the month index to be equal to the month number currently looping?

Comment: Ok i've set the monthIndex correctly using the key in (key, month) in customer.months

Comment: Ah yes, `months` is a hash, not an array. So do you have it working? For future reference, it would be helpful to provide an example of what you want the output to be.